# Looping through a query into separate tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I call my query ok

```
    $sql = "Call new_c02(1,1,'2014-01-10','2014-01-10')";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
    }
```

and it generates a table thus:

```
Acc  Data1  Data2  Data3    
1    x     y     z
1    a     b    c
2    x     y    z
2    a     b    c
```

I can throw this into a table using

```
<table> <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>                  
<tr>
  <td>
  <?php    echo $row['accounts'] . '<br />'; ?>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

etc etc

However I would like to be able to generate a separate table for every different account so i have a table for Acc 1 and a separate table below it for Acc2 and so on until I am exhausted of Accs in the query.
Just not sure how to loop through the query to make a separate table for each

Help really appreciated
Simon

Comment: That’s what’s called a _control break_. You simple compare the actual value of the break criterion (the account number in your case) to the one from the previous record, and if they don’t match, you do something special (in this case, closing one table and opening another one).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep track of which Acc numbers you've output already, and if the current one hasn't been output, create a new table. Something like this should do the trick:

```
<?php
$acc_output = array();
$is_first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    // set this according to your array structure            
    $acc_id = $row['accounts']['Acc']; 

    // if this is the first row, open a table
    if($is_first)
        echo '<table>';

    // if it's not the first row, and it is a new acc ID
    // close current table and open a new table
    if(!$is_first && !in_array($acc_id))
        echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL . '<table>';

    // add current acc_id to the array
    $acc_output[] = $acc_id;
    // set not first
    $is_first = false;

    ?>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <?php    echo $row['accounts'] . '<br />'; ?>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <?php

}

// then, close the last table
?>
</table>
```

To use your example data in a test case:

```
Acc  Data1  Data2  Data3    
1    x     y    z       - is_first, open new table
1    a     b    c       - not first, is in array - do nothing        
2    x     y    z       - not first, not in array - close/open new table
2    a     b    c       - not first, is in array - do nothing
- end, close table
```